# What does a caret + brace do within a bash variable?

Tags: bash

What does a caret do when appended to a bash variable but within braces? I'm trying to decipher this within a bash script:

```
readonly TEST=${USER^}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I don't know the meaning of some syntax in bash/sh I use my browsers find function in [bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) and [sh's specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). This is pretty effective as both contain the *entire* manual in a single page.

From bash's manual:

> ```
> ${parameter^pattern}
> ```
>
> [...]
> The ‘^’ operator converts lowercase letters matching pattern to uppercase
> [...]
> If pattern is omitted, it is treated like a ‘?’, which matches every character.

So `${variable^}` expands to the value of `$variable` with the first letter converted to its uppercase variant.

Comment: "So ${variable^} expands to the value of $variable with all letters converted to their uppercase variant." -- that's not the case. only the first char is converted to uppercase. `${var^^}` converts all chars. (yes it's one of the most confusing bash syntax.)

Comment: in the manual it has "the `^` and `,` expansions match and convert **only the first character** in  the  expanded  value"

Comment: @pynexj Thank you very much for this correction. I only wrote this answer because I wanted to share my way of finding the official documentation for that syntax, so I didn't give much thought to the actual answer and this mistake happened... my bad. However, I just noticed that the documentation is somewhat misleading. As it says *"^ ... converts **lowercase letters matching** pattern to uppercase"* I would have assumed `var=Abc; echo ${var^}` to print `ABc` as `b` is the first **lowercase** letter matching `?`. I guess there is no way around actually checking the real output to be sure.

Comment: right. to me it makes more sense to get rid of the "pattern" part at all. that's to say, `${var^}` only converts the first char (not the first letter) and `${var^^}` the whole string.